VSCode Java Autocomplete Not Working After Line Break Comment in Method Chaining with Lambdas
I’m experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code when writing Java code. Specifically, when I add // at the end of a line to force a line break for formatting purposes, the autocomplete feature of the Extension Pack for Java stops working properly.
Details:

Java Version: OpenJDK 17
Extension Pack for Java: v0.29.0

My settings.json configuration for Java:
{
  ...
  "[java]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "redhat.java"
    },
  "java.format.settings.profile": "GoogleStyle",
  ...
}

Example Code
basecode
interface InterfaceSomething {
    void doSomething();
}

class Something {
    private InterfaceSomething inter1;
    private InterfaceSomething inter2;

    public Something setInter1(InterfaceSomething inter1) {
        this.inter1 = inter1;
        return this;
    }

    public Something setInter2(InterfaceSomething inter2) {
        this.inter2 = inter2;
        return this;
    }
}

Example without "//"
new Something()
  .setInter1(() -> {
    System.out.println("doSomething1");
  })
  .set// Autocomplete suggests methods after typing '.' ("setInter1" or "setInter2")
                .

Example with "//" (Autocomplete does not work):
new Something()
  .setInter1(() -> {
    System.out.println("doSomething1"); // Adding '//' here to force a line break
  })
  .set// Autocomplete does not suggest methods after typing '.' or "Trigger Suggest" Command 

Question:

Why does adding // at the end of a line affect the autocomplete functionality in VSCode when writing Java code with method chaining and lambda functions?
Is there a way to fix this issue or an alternative method to enforce line breaks without disrupting autocomplete?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
What I’ve Tried but not work

Restarting VSCode.
Reinstalling the Extension Pack for Java.
"Language Support for Java(TM) by Red" Command "Java: Clean Java Language Server Workspace"


What you are trying to achieve?When you place //you are starting to make a comment in code and IntelliCode will not trying to autocomplete code in comment.
